# Maven version is not displaying

Tags: maven

I am using Mac book air and installed `apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar`, and unzipped it.
The maven folder which got created I have moved to `/Users/ak/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3`

Then created `.bash_profile` under `/Users/ak/Applications` and provided following details and saved the files

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/ak/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Now when i tried `ak@ak-MacBook-Air ~ % mvn -version`
I am getting following error:

`zsh: command not found: mvn`

Comment: Try load the file: `source .bash_profile` or restart your terminal window

Comment: it works fine ak@ak-MacBook-Air ~ % source .bash_profile
ak@ak-MacBook-Air ~ % mvn -version but the moment i close the terminal and reopen it and provide mvn -version then i get zsh: command not found: mvn

Comment: Your `.bash_profile` file should be located under `/Users/ak`. Try again this way, after restarting your terminal.

Comment: i did that but didnt worked, infact i have kept apache-maven-3.6.3 and .bash_profile undr /User/ak and changed profile to export M2_HOME=/Users/ak/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin but the moment i restart the terminal it wont works :(

Comment: First remove `M2_HOME` because you don't need it...only add the bin directory of the distribution to your PATH... furthermore if you use zsh you should use   `.zshenv` or `.zprofile` best would be look into the docs... http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Comment: not working, changed .bash_profile to export M2_HOME=/Users/ak/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=/bin

Comment: I have changed .bash_profile to following but still mvn not found error  #set JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME


M2_HOME=/Users/arunkrishnanapache-maven-3.6.3
export M2_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH